# All values turned up NaN and NA after data correction and normalization in R

Tags: r, nan, normalization, bioconductor

I have a set of 21500 data, I performed background correction and normalization using bioconductor packages MBCB.main however the result is only NaN values for one column and NA values for the other. Can anybody tell me why is this happening? I have 2 sets of data, signal and control.

Signal:

```
structure(list(ID_REF = c("TC0100006437.hg.1", 
"TC0100006476.hg.1", "TC0100006479.hg.1", "TC0100006480.hg.1", 
"TC0100006483.hg.1"), 
GSM4557962 = c(44.944035, 100.85072, 157.17555, 89.425964, 
68.77652), 
GSM4557965 = c(42.962048, 
126.33466, 139.22046, 139.04102, 79.80324)), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))`
```

Control:

```
structure(list(ID_REF = 
c("TC0100006437.hg.1","TC0100006476.hg.1", "TC0100006479.hg.1", 
"TC0100006480.hg.1", "TC0100006483.hg.1"), 
GSM4557961 = c(46.799675, 127.531555, 212.54181, 121.27715, 
70.95126), 
GSM4557964 = c(49.06907, 147.042, 206.33817, 126.067024, 
60.933674)), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl","data.frame"))
```

And this is the background correction + normalization function I am using (replacing with my files)

```
MBCB:: mbcb.main (signal,
control,
npBool=TRUE,
rmaBool=FALSE,
mleBool=FALSE,
bayesBool=FALSE,
gmleBool=FALSE,
paramEstFile="param-est",
bgCorrectedFile="bgCorrected",
iter=500,
burn=200,
normMethod="median",
isRawBead=FALSE)
```

The result is a BgCorrSig file with NP correction and normalization with NaN and NA values in X1 and X2 columns respectively.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I just added a subset of my data the samples and control data sets, and the code i am using for the background correction and normalization with bioconductor.